# Spring boot jar сервер на веб хостинге

Tags: java, ssh, jar, spring-boot, virtual-hosts

Всем привет. Коротко: Зарегистрировался на https://cp.hts.ru/ получив виртуальный хостинг(no root), закинул по ssh в /home/srv75429/  spring boot jar-ник, скачал java, запустил командой ./java -jar spring.jar, запустился норм всё замечательно(удалённая база данных также обновилась) и вот захожу на свой сайт srv75429.ht-test.ru но сервер не видит, далее я понял что все запросы идут на общий ip адрес по порту 80 и он потом переадресовывает в мою папку /home/srv75429/
в которой лежит мой сайт, а сайта там нет потому что его генерирует spring boot на порту 8080, по-гуглив я узнал что нужно сделать переадресацию на порт 8080 через nginx, но рут прав у меня нет, решил собрать nginx из исходников, но там там требуется c compiler, начал собирать c compiler с исходников но там тоже какой-то c нужен и получить его можно командой yum с рут правами. Решаю задачу уже 4 день. возможно что-то не так понимаю. C удалённой установкой java сервера сталкиваюсь впервые.

код properties:

```
server.address = localhost
server.contextPath=/home/srv75429/


spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx/mysql
spring.datasource.username = xxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password = xxxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1



spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

код MainController

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
public String index() {
return "<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\"      src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/xBd0qtGaNLY\" frameborder=\"0\"     allowfullscreen></iframe>";  }

}
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: А на 80-порту пробовал embedded tomcat стартовать? Попробуй указать `server.address = srv75429.ht-test.ru` и `server.port = 80` или сделай проброс 8080 порта

Comment: Привет, с 'server.address = srv75429.ht-test.ru' выбивает 'java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address' с портом 80 тоже Exception т.к.  порт 80 занят, как сделать пробросить порт 8080 я не знаю, подскажи если в курсе или кинь ссылку почитать. Спасибо!

Comment: @rvit чтоб занять 80 порт необходимы рут права. на ум не приходит ничего где не нужны были бы права рута

Comment: Вам нужен не хостинг, а полноценный VPS.

Comment: Когда я устанавливал сервер на хостинг и подключал его к своему домену, то согласовывал такую установку с технической поддержкой хостинга. Эти ребята взяли на себя некоторую работу и помогли всё настроить. Кроме всего прочего, они порекомендовали какие инструкции почитать. Как правило хостинг настроен на работу с папкой public_html, в случае установки своего сервера это нужно изменить. Если у Вас есть возможность попробуйте обратиться к техподдержке.